# Strtok not inserting a null terminator?

Tags: c, token, strtok

Here is my function for breaking up SIC assembly line. 
Here's an example line from my inputFile

```
FIRST   STL     RETADR      SAVE RETURN ADDRESS
```

What gets written to the file is:

```
RETADR      SAVE RETURN ADDRESS
```

---

```
void tokenizeLine(int format)
{
fgets(inputLine,150,inputFile);
    char * label, * opcode, * operand, inputLine[150];//Variables to hold tokens
    char whiteSpaceDelim[] = " \t\r\n\v";//whitespaces

    //FORMAT1: LABEL, OPCODE, OPERAND
    //FORMAT2: OPCODE, OPERAND
    if(format==FORMAT1)
    {
        label = strtok(inputLine,whiteSpaceDelim);
        opcodePointer = strtok(NULL,whiteSpaceDelim);
        operand = strtok(NULL,whiteSpaceDelim);
        comment = strtok(NULL,whiteSpaceDelim);//used to place a \0 at the end of operand pointer
    }
    else//must be format 2
    {
        opcodePointer = strtok(inputLine,whiteSpaceDelim);
        operand = strtok(NULL,whiteSpaceDelim);
        comment = strtok(NULL,whiteSpaceDelim);
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to use `fprintf` to write *only* the operand to the intermediate file, I instead get the comments that follow it as well. Is `comment = strtok(NULL,whiteSpaceDelim)` not placing a `\0` at the end of operand?

```
fprintf(intermediateFile,"%s\n\n",operand);//step 4) write operand to file
```

Comment: I do not see `inputLine` being populated.

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help (why isn't this code working?) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]._

Comment: Your code lacks most important things. Input, Format, ... Why is the `printf` not included in the function? What did your debugger tell you when you step through your code?

Comment: You have put fgets(inputLine,150,inputFile); before inputLine actually gets declared.

Comment: Post a copy/paste of the real code.